# Using Google Translate API Read Functionality with PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, google-translate

Is there a way to use Google Translate API Read Functionality with PhoneGap? PhoneGap is basically a WebKit Wrapper, so I'd like to use REST. Possible? And where can I see what languages the read functionality support?

Comment: Can you point to the "reading functionality" you are referring to in the Translation API? It does not seem to be currently part of it when looking at the API's [Reference](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest). 

As for your second question, here’s a list of Translation API’s supported [languages](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/languages) and a good description on how to send a [supported](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/discovering-supported-languages) languages request via a HTTP GET method.

Answer (score 1):

They have a really easy to use RESTfull API.
for more details:

https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started#REST

Comment: Of course I've been on this site but I couldn't read anything about the reading functionality.